# Очень высокий fps в UNITY 19.3.0

Tags: unity3d

Подскажите пожалуйста, скачал UNITY 2019.3.0 и при запуске проэкта в UNITY, fps очень высокий, а при запуске на телефоне все как обычно. Можно ли как то установить fps лимит в UNITY, или почему такой аномальный fps?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну например потому что сцена несложная и видеокарта хорошая? Не такой уж и аномальный fps, мой старенький ноутбук тоже несколько тысяч кадров выдаёт, если графику по минимуму выкрутить

Comment: ну допустим, а почему тогда на более ранних версиях fps в разы ниже, возможно это глюк, от переноса проэкта с другой версии unity, спасибо.

Comment: Ну вообще ПО имеет тенденцию развиваться в том числе и в плане производительности. А так без конкретных примеров и графиков из профайлера невозможно сказать, что у вас и как.

Comment: И окно Stats показывает примерный fps, это ни в коем случае не равносильно действительно "правильному" fps в билде.

Comment: запустил более старую версию unity 2019.2.2 и fps в ней 70 и никак не за 1к. Просто при таком fps, объекты двигаются намного быстрее, а это проблема, так как при переносе на устройство все совсем не так и никаким fps в 1к и не пахнет

Comment: создал новый проект и о чудо, fps стал... за 2.5к

Comment: Значит у вас fps-зависимый геймплей, чтобы такого избежать, нужно использовать `Time.deltaTime`. А вообще фпс на телефонах ограничивается принудительной вертикальной синхронизацией, вы можете ее и в редакторе подключить.

Comment: RiotBr3aker спасибо, DeltaTime то что нужно!

Answer (score 0):

Можешь это сделать через скрипт: [Документация Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-targetFrameRate.html). Ограничить fps может быть полезно, особенно в меню, дабы сэкономить на телефоне батарейку.

Comment: При установке APK на телефон, объекты двигаются раз в 5 медленне чем в юнити. Пока что решил проблему добавив ко всем движениям Time.deltatime. что в юнити, что в телефоне скорость совпадает, вроде как.